# Color TextBlock depending on enum value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textblock

I'm working on WPF with a MvvM model.

I have a view containing Texblocks. It display information about ID (from a document and from a database) :

```
<GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Header="ID Informations">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="DataBase surname: "/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Db_SURNAME}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Document surname: "/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Dc_SURNAME}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBlock Text="DataBase forename: "/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Db_FORENAME}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Document forename: "/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Dc_FORENAME}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

I have an enum containing an error code :

```
[Flags]
public enum errorID
{
    OK = 1<<0,
    SURNAME_DIFF = 1 << 1,
    FORENAME_DIFF = 1 << 2
}
```

And my model is wrote like this :

```
private String _db_SURNAME;
public String Db_SURNAME
{
    get { return _db_SURNAME; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _db_SURNAME, value); }
}
[...]

private errorID _errorID;
public errorID ErrorID
{
    get { return _errorID; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _errorID, value); }
}
```

I want that both of my textblocks displaying `Model.Db_SURNAME` and `Model.Dc_SURNAME` are colored in red when `ErrorID.HasFlag(errorID.SURNAME_DIFF )`. And also for `Forname`.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a converter that converts your enum to a color like following:

```
public class ErrorIdColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(!(value is errorID))
             throw new ArgumentException("value not of type errorID");
        if(!(parameteris errorID))
             throw new ArgumentException("parameter not of type errorID");

        errorID error = (errorID)value;
        errorID flag = (errorID)parameter;

        if (error.HasFlag(flag))
        {
            return Brushes.Red;
        }
        ...

        return Brushes.Black;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   ....
}
```

}

Then you can bind the Foreground Color to your enum using the converter:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Db_SURNAME}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground={Binding Model.errorId, Converter={StaticRessource errorIDColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticRessource errorID.SURNAME_DIFF}}/>
```

Comment: TextBlock.Foreground is a brush, not a color.

Comment: Sorry, you are right then return a new Brush instead of color

Comment: Foreground uses SolidColorBrush

Comment: I looked for your solution, but it will color in red always when error is `errorID.SURNAME_DIFF`. I poorly formulated my question, I want coloring textblocks surname when surname id different, but I want to color forename when forename is different (i'll edit my question)

Comment: @Clemens why using enum.HasFlag instead of switch - case ? What is the improvement ?

Comment: Do you know what a flags enum is? All flags can be present at the same time. In a switch statement you only check for single values.

Comment: @SébastienKrejci I modified your code with : `if (eCode.HasFlag((ErrorCode)parameter))` and in my xaml : `Converter={StaticResource ErrorIdColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource errorID.SURNAME_DIFF}}` and it works ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to go for `DataTrigger` on your `ErrorID` property of your `Model`.

Try something like this:

1. Add a namespace of your `enum` to your `View` (Visual Studio will help you get it correct)

   ```
   <UserControl [some other namespaces] 
                xmlns:someName="clr-namespace:YourEnumNamespace;assembly=YourAssembly">
   ```
2. Add styling for your `TextBox` (you can set it for all of them at once by doing this, or add `x:Key` to reference style explicitly for each `TextBox` you want to have it):

   ```
   <UserControl.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
           <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding [your property to bind]}" Value="{x:Static someName:ErrorID.[value of enum]}">
                   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
               </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
           <!-- repeat data triggers for each enum value you want to check !-->
       </Style>
   </UserControl.Resources>
   ```

Or go for converter, but I personally prefer that approach.

If an approach with having that style in `UserControl.Resources` won't work for you because you are not able to bind like this, just put it in your `TextBox.Style` tag under your `TextBox`.

Comment: How does this work with a flags enum? See `ErrorID.HasFlag(errorID.SURNAME_DIFF)` in the question.

Comment: As a note, for a regular enum you can simply use the enum literal string in the Value of a DataTrigger, like `Value="SURNAME_DIFF"`. No need for x:Static.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution: binding `Foreground` color by the value of `ErrorID`

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Db_SURNAME}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground={Binding SurNameColor}/>
<TextBlock Text="Document surname: "/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Dc_SURNAME}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground={Binding SurNameColor}/>
```

**Model**

```
private Brush _surNameColor = Brush.Black;
public Brush SurNameColor
{
    get { return _surNameColor; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _surNameColor, value); }
}
private errorID _errorID;
public errorID ErrorID
{
    get { return _errorID; }
    set { 
        if(ErrorID.HasFlag(errorID.SURNAME_DIFF))
            SurNameColor = Brushes.Red;
        SetProperty(ref _errorID, value); }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but binding to color in your Model is just awful from MVVM point of view. It breaks conventions. I will produce a more consistent with MVVM answer for you in few minutes.

Comment: @KacperStachowski Which conventions does it break exactly? Please provide a reference.

Comment: @Clemens Maybe separation of concerns? I think the viewmodel should be about data, XAML and code behind about representation. Off course binding to a Property in the viewmodel works, but I agree to Kasper, it is not the most elegant solution.

Comment: @ChristianMurschall Having a color string in a *view* model doesn't break any convention (IMO). You won't find any reputable reference saying you shouldn't do that. People here are often confusing their point of view or their opinion with a convention.

Comment: @Clemens I updated the answer. Not tested but I think color string can't work, must use Brush instead

Comment: @ThierryV Brush is better, and perfectly valid in a view model, as long as you don't want to reuse it with a different UI framework. I must however admit that I would prefer a Binding Converter.

Comment: @Clemens: That is right. And it is also backed by the MVVM [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm): Each view model provides data from a model in a form that the view can **easily consume**. To accomplish this, the view model **sometimes performs data conversion.**
This said, I still like the DataTrigger solution more, might be a personal taste.

Comment: @ChristianMurschall In case *you* upvoted the DataTrigger answer, be aware that it **won't work**. The question is about a **flags enum**, not a regular one. OP should use a Binding Converter, and indeed they do.